# How can I assign a null boolean to a field in an anonymous class?

Tags: c#

I have the following in WebAPI that is converted to a JSON string and sent to the client:

```
return Ok(new
    {
        Answer = "xxx",
        Answers = question.Answers.Select((a, i) => new
        {
            AnswerId = (string) null,
            AnswerUId = i + 1,
            Response = null,
            Text = a.Text
        })
    });
```

Is there a way that I can set a field called Response to null?  When I try to cast this to (bool) it does not seem to work.

Comment: Bool can't be null. Closest thing is to use `Nullable<bool>`, but I don't know what the JSON stuff will do with that. Try `Response = (bool?)null` and see what it does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried casting to `(bool?)` or failing that, `(Nullable<bool>)`?

`bool` is a non-nullable value type, you must wrap the `bool` in the [`Nullable<T>` Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

try assigning

```
Response = default(bool?);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try  `new Nullable<bool>()`